# Inequality on sums

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, inequality

Consider the following problem:

Given $M, N$ positive integers and $\{(m,n)\}$ be a collections of pairs of non-negative real numbers satisfying with $m \leq M, n \leq N$ and $m+n = k$, where $k$ is a positive integer, consider the claim:

There are $A, B$ real numbers such that $AB < 0$ and

$$AM + BN < 0,$$
$$Am + Bn > 0,$$
forall $(m,n)$,

if, and only if, there are no pairs $(m_1,n_1), (m_2,n_2)$ with
$$m_1 \leq \frac{Mk}{M+N} \leq m_2.$$

Now I am interested on the following natural generalization:

Given $(M_1,...,M_r)$ positive integer numbers, a collection $\{(t_1,...,t_r)\}$ real numbers, such that for each $(m_1,...,m_r)$ sequence of real non-negative numbers with $m_i \leq M_i$ and  $m_1 + ... + m_r = k$, for a positive integer $k$,

$$t_1m_1 + .... + t_rm_r > 0$$
$$t_1M_1 + ... + t_rM_r < 0.$$

I was expecting to obtain any relation related to the previous for "two dimensional case". Any hints??? I tried to reduce to the previous case but I failed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You require $AB<0$, but I don't see how that is reflected in the generalization. Also, I'm guessing you meant to write
$$Am+Bn>0$$

Comment: @adfriedman, yes, tou are right, I mean $Am + Bn< 0$. About the generalization, at least one $t_i$ must bem negative.

Comment: So, I mean, $t_1\ldots t_r < 0.$

Comment: Further, for every $i$, $m_i$ is non-negative.